# How to get different timezones' current time in PHP?

Tags: php, timezone

Unfortunately I'm not using PHP 5. On the documentation of the [date](http://php.net/date) function it has a timezone section which lets you specify the difference from the GMT tome. How can you use that to get the current/local time in a specified timezone, and does it with with daylights savings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert times to different timezones by using the PEAR Date package http://pear.php.net/package/Date

Examples here http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.datetime.date.examples.php